# How to run a groovy script from a grade task interpreted, not compiled?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a little groovy script that just generates a small report about a special aspect of the source code. It is NOT required in the build process and it shall NOT be part of the resulting jar file. It's just a little script that will be run manually from time to time to get some special information.

Let's say the script is to be found here (outside of the `src` folder): `./misc/groovy-scripts/generate-special-report.groovy` and it contains only `println "Special report generated"` (too keep things simple here).
How can I run this groovy script from a gradle task, without having to provide an extra/additional groovy installation on the system?

Answers, ideas, tips and hints must not 100% satisfy the above mentioned requirements, I'm happy about any help/solution.
But I hope there's an alternative solution to this one here:
[Running Groovy scripts from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360719/running-groovy-scripts-from-gradle)

---

[Edit] Maybe `GroovyShell` or `GroovyScriptEngine` is what I'm looking for as described in some comments here: [Run groovy script from within gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360513/run-groovy-script-from-within-gradle)
I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: GroovyShell should work